# Hibernate map ManyToOne in child entity to a field in a Composite Key of Parent Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `BookEntity` class that have a composite id comprising of `id` and `publishedDate` columns in Book table.

Then, I have a `BookMetaDataEntity` class that has its own id `metaDataId`.

The relationship is that one book has many meta data rows. `BookEntity` joins `BookMetaDataEntity` on the first's `id` column with the second's `bookId` column. Vice versa, I also define `JoinColum` on the second entity.

**BookEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeId compositeId;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = BookMetaDataEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "bookId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<BookMetaDataEntity> metaData;
}
```

**CompositeId.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "publishedDate")
    private int publishedDate;
}
```

**BookMetaDataEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BookMetaData")
public class BookMetaDataEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "metaDataId")
    private int metaDataId;

    @Column(name = "bookId")
    private int bookId;

    @Column(name = "attribute")
    private String attribute;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = BookEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable) 
    private Book book;
}
```

**Issue**: referencedColumnNames(id) of BookMetaDataEntity.book referencing BookEntity not mapped to a single property.

The joining happens only on the `id` = `bookId` because the `BookMetaData` table does not have a `publishedDate` column.

How do I mapped back from a child entity to a field in a composite key of the parent entity?

Comment: I think you need to take the way via the `compositeId`. This means that the field path would be `compositeId.id` and  `compositeId.publishedDate`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i tried `@JoinColumn(name = "bookId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable) ` but it says Unable to find column with logical name: compositeId.id